# How to dereference Object created by Mongoengine using Mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongoose, mongoengine

I've written a number of scripts in Python that collects data from various sources and dumps it into a MongoDB using Mongoengine across 3 different collections.  One of these collections' documents (interfaces) references documents in one of the other two collections (v_machines, p_machines) that host different schemas of data.  As a beginner to nodejs, I am not sure how to dereference the references when using Mongoose.

I tried using the populate() method but am quickly returned with the following error:

```
{
    "statusCode": 500,
    "error": "Internal Server Error",
    "message": "Cast to ObjectId failed for value \"Machine\" at path \"_id\" for model \"interfaces\""
}
```

Using a GenericReferenceField in MongoEngine, the an example of the schema looks like the following:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("8c49db2f45546d3a586877a6"),
    "name" : "testbox.blah.com",
    "mac_address" : "c4:cc:fa:bd:49:66",
    "label" : "eth0",
    "machine_reference" : {
        "_cls" : "Machine",
        "_ref" : {
            "$ref" : "p_machines",
            "$id" : ObjectId("5c32cb2f46546c4a586877a5")
        }
    }
}
```

This looks a bit different from examples I've seen using .populate().  The "_cls" reference isn't there from my searches.  It looks like I have to go down another level to maybe get the data.

In my js code, I have the model defined as:

```
const interface_schema = new mongoose.Schema({
  id: {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, index: true, required: true},
  machine_reference: {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.Mixed, index: true, required: true},
  name: {type: String, index: true, required: true},
  mac_address: {type: String, required: true},
  label: {type: String, required: true},
})
```

Query code here:

```
interfaces.find({ 'name': req.query.name }).populate('machine_reference')
```

I would like to be able to dereference the respective documents for both collections.  How would I go about doing this?  Open to suggestions, even recreating the schema, or changing the model.

Answer (score 0):

In your schema have to change this type:

```
machine_reference: {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, index: true, required: true, ref:'name of the model'}
```

Be careful in the ref part, it has to be the name you gave to machine reference schema e.g. Machine. Don't forget to enclose it in quotes. Hope it resolves the issue.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response!  Looks like that didn't work, I am returned with the same error.  On a related note, my machine_reference key references either the Machine or vMachine collection.  Wouldn't setting it up this way only allow me to dereference "Machine"s and not "vMachine"s?